# PHP VideoStream class in SilverStripe

Tags: php, mp4, silverstripe, webm

I'm using [VideoStream](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293) class and it works very well. I try to integrate it inside a `Page_Controller` and secure the video from being uploaded. So each time the page is loaded the video link always change on reload and nobody can download it directly from the browser URL.

But the class doesn't seem to work and I don't know what I've missed. I'm also using the [ChunkedUpload](https://github.com/micschk/silverstripe-chunkeduploadfield) module to upload big files into the CMS.

Any ideas how use that class?

Here is my code.

Note: My code works I've note below "my original..."

**PageVideo.ss**

```
<video controls preload="auto" id="video1">
    <% if $VideoMP4 %><source src="id/$Video($VideoMP4.ID)" type="video/mp4"><% end_if %>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**PageVideo.php**

```
class PageVideo extends Page {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'VideoMP4' => 'File'
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Main ',
            $uploadField = new ChunkedUploadField(
                $name = 'VideoMP4',
                $title = "VideoMP4"
            )
        );

        $uploadField->setFolderName('Uploads/videos/');
        $uploadField->setDisplayFolderName('Uploads/videos');
        $uploadField->getValidator()->allowedExtensions = array("mp4");

        $sizeMB = 500 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 MB in bytes
        $uploadField->getValidator()->setAllowedMaxFileSize($sizeMB);
        $uploadField->setConfig('maxChunkSize', .05 * 1024 * 1024 );

        return $fields;
    }
}

class PageVideo_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array('VideoGrab');
    private static $url_handlers = array('id/$hash' => 'VideoGrab');

    public function VideoGrab(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

        $hash = $request->param('hash');

        $file = File::get()->filter('ID', $_SESSION['keyID'])->first();

        if (md5($file->Name . $_SESSION['key']) == $hash) {

            $_SESSION['key'] = "";
            $_SESSION['keyID'] = "";

            //**************** HERE IS THE CLASS *********************
            include "libraries/VideoStream.php";
            $stream = new VideoStream($file->AbsoluteURL);
            $stream->start();
            exit;

            // the original php working just for some browsing and bad codes
            /*
            $ext = pathinfo($file->Filename);
            header('Cache-control: private');
            header('Content-Type: video/' . $ext['extension']);
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

            return readfile($file->AbsoluteURL);
            exit;
            */
        } else {
            return $this->httpError(404, "Not Found");
        }
    }

    public function Video($n) {

        $file = File::get()->filter('ID', $n)->First();
        $_SESSION['key'] = time();
        $_SESSION['keyID'] = $file->ID;

        return md5($file->Name . $_SESSION['key']);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the source code of the result page (video part) ? Did you have the expected values on the src="" attribute of <source /> ?

Comment: the video source VideoMP4 is holded by has_one array in page model. Did you have experience with Silverstripe?

Comment: @3dgoo, thanks for cleaning my english and codes! Do you have an answer? You seem to be a guru of Silverstripe coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this.

**Class**

```
class PageVideo extends Page {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'VideoMP4' => 'File'
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Video', $uploadField = UploadField::create('VideoMP4'));

        $uploadField->setFolderName('Uploads/videos/');
        $uploadField->getValidator()->allowedExtensions = array('mp4');

        return $fields;
    }
}

class PageVideo_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'VideoStream'
    );

    function VideoStream() {
        if ($this->VideoMP4()->exists()) {
            include 'libraries/VideoStream.php';
            $stream = new VideoStream($this->VideoMP4()->getFullPath());
            return $stream->start();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<% if $VideoMP4 %>
<video controls preload="auto" id="video1">
    <source src="{$Link}VideoStream" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! I have just to replace my $stream variable to yours.             $stream = new VideoStream($this->VideoMP4()->getFullPath());
thanks and thanks alot. I didnt know getFullPath() command.